# Meeting with R participants

Tags: graph-theory

A meeting has R participants. All participants arrive and leave at different times, but it is always true that within any 3 of them there is always at least 1, who has met the other 2.
Prove that then there is at least one person who met with all the other participants.

Comment: This is not true for R = 4.  For example, if A has met B, B has met C, C has met D, and D has met A, but A has not met  C, and B has not met D.  The criteria are satisfied, but none of participants has met all the others.

Comment: @user329406, Exactly! I found the same contr-example - a rectangle.

Comment: Is the arrival/departure time relevant here ?  For instance, it could imply the condition that if two people were at the meeting at the same time, then they must have met.  Who met whom would actually depend on the time intervals of presence, and you wouldn't get a rectangle.  If time isn't relevant though then yeah it's a counter-example.

Comment: @user3294068 Time has to be taken into account so your contra- example is false since that arrangement is impossible. 
I still can't work out the proof for this one though so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would never assume that "A and B were present at the same time" was synonymous with "A and B met".  I've been to many meetings where I haven't met all of the other participants.

Comment: I'm sorry for being unclear. I translated this question from spanish to english, so that's the source of the problem.
Sorry again and thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace the phrase "has met" with "were both present at the same time", then the solution (for $R \geq 3$) is as follows:

Consider the first person to leave and the last person to arrive.  If the first person left after the last person arrived, then there was a time when everyone was present at once.  QED

If the first person left before the last person arrived, then consider any third person.  By your criteria, of the group (first, last, other), one of them must have been present when each of the others was present, and since there was no overlap for first & last, that person must be other.  Since everyone left after (or at the same time as) first left and everyone arrived before (or at the same time as) last arrived, this other person must have been present at the same time as each other person.

In fact, everyone except the first to leave and last to arrive must have had an overlap with every other person.

Which brings us to the case where $R = 2$.  If the first person left before the last person arrived, the criteria are still satisfied since there are no groups of three people.  On the other hand, if there were only two participants and the first one left before the second arrived, it can hardly be called a "meeting."